# Translate sql query to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nosql

Hi im newbie into MongoDB and im needing to translate this sql query to mongodb using two techniques first in MapReduce method and other Aggregation method. Someone may help?

```
select
    sum(l_extendedprice*l_discount) as revenue
from 
    lineitem
where 
    l_shipdate >= date '1994-01-01'
    and l_shipdate < date '1994-01-01' + interval '1' year
    and l_discount between 0.06 - 0.01 and 0.06 + 0.01
    and l_quantity < 24;
```

Comment: A lot of this can be achieved post query programmatically... what language/driver are you using for mongo, or is it the mongo shell (js)?

Comment: Is this a homework question? :)  Why do you need two techniques, and what have you tried based on reading the documentation for [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) and [Aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation) ?

Comment: To compare what way is most simple to write and intelligible

Comment: @ulima69 OK .. your example SQL query appears borrowed from the [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/) benchmark so looked like [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  In terms of ease of writing, that's probably more a question of your own experience and what [language driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) you are using to access MongoDB.  It's good practice to at least attempt to investigate your own question before asking for help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

For your sample, using map/reduce

```
var m = function () { emit(1, {this.l_extendedprice * this.l_discount})};

var r = function (k, vals) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
       sum += vals[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

var res = db.stuff.mapReduce(m, r,  {
                            out:"stuff_aggr",
                            query: { 
                                "l_shipdate": {$gte:  ISODate("1994-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}, 
                                "l_shipdate": {$lte:  ISODate("1995-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
                                "l_discount": {$gte: 0.05}, 
                                "l_discount": {$lte: 0.07}, 
                                "l_quantity": {$lt: 24}
                            }
});
```

[Aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation)  is still a beta feature. MapReduce is still the better option. Am assuming you wanted to see if a complex where clause can be handled easily... Its not that different from SQL as long as you are restricting yourself to one collection/table.

Comment: Yes Aggregation promises will be more intuitive then mapreduce. Mongo papper about mapreduce is not too clear for me. Im starting to understand mapreduce reading this article http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial

Comment: The original [Google paper on Map Reduce](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) is also an interesting read.

Comment: Amith George one question, why the firts parameter of emit funtion is 1? Could be this._id? Or why not?

Comment: Your first parameter is what you group by. Your original sql did not contain a group by. It just returned one row. In mongodb case, all results will be grouped by the first parameter. As all documents will have the same value for that column, ie 1, we will eventually only get back one result document.